# Why pointer is not const in the method argument?

Tags: c++

I have an API as following.

```
bool query_nonblocking(const char * const query, 
unsigned long length) {
// Read the buffer only once.
// Do some work, return false to  retry. 

return true; 
}
```

**Underlying API assumption is that data and pointer both should not be changed.** 
I thought having the const pointer as const char should be sufficient but it is not. I see that compiler choose to ignore the const keyword intended for the pointer.

```
query_nonblocking(char const*, unsigned long):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Refer [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-P4b54)

I expected the following code to fail to compile because the str() returns string by value that will keep on changing on every call that will invalidate the buffer read  in the beginning. 
But it compiles without any problem.  I think that happens because the pointer is not const after the compilation.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "SELECT MD5('XXXXXX')";
bool flag =  query_nonblocking(ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length());
while(flag != true) {

flag = query_nonblocking(ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length());

}
```

My questions are :
(1) Why does the pointer is not constant in the method argument after compilation.

(2) Is there a way to prevent usage shown like above when API expects the pointer and buffer must not be modified.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Notice that in `char const*` the `const` is before the `*` which is equivalent to `const char *`. And the second `const` doesn't matter from the caller's point of view. `query_nonblocking(char const*, unsigned long)` and `query_nonblocking(const char * const query, 
unsigned long length)` are called identically, with the exact same constraints. I think you just misread the output of the compiler.

Comment: `const` is part of the C++ language. Few hardware platforms have anything like "const" values on the assembly level.

Comment: You say that you "thought having the const pointer as const char should be sufficient"... Sufficient for *what*? What is the real problem you're having? Why would the code you show need to be prevented?

Comment: `str()` returns by value, but that value is valid until the expression ends. So the pointer returned by `c_str()` is valid until `query_nonblocking` returns. And `c_str()` returns a `const` pointer which `query_nonblocking` expects. There is no obvious reason to expect the code code shown to fail to compile.

Comment: If a function expects a `const` argument, you can give it a non-`const` argument and it will accept it. A `const` function argument doesn't mean the function *only* accepts a `const`. It means it won't modify that argument. So you can still pass a non-`const` pointer to `query_nonblocking` and it should work fine.

Comment: "I see that compiler choose to ignore the const keyword intended for the pointer." Where do you see that? This affirmation is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought having the const pointer as const char should be sufficient but it is not

A pointer to const means that indirecting through the pointer yields a const lvalue (reference). Having a const lvalue simply means that you cannot modify the object through the lvalue.

Thus, having a pointer to const merely means that you cannot modify the object through the pointer:

```
bool query_nonblocking(const char * const query, 
unsigned long length) {
    query[0] = 'x'; // ill-formed, because of pointer to const
```

*Pointer to const does not mean that the pointed object is necessarily const. Nor does it mean that the pointed data cannot change.*

---

Having a const pointer simply means that you cannot make the pointer point to somewhere else:

```
bool query_nonblocking(const char * const query, 
unsigned long length) {
    query = "another string"; // ill-formed, because of const pointer
```

<sup>1</sup> *Const argument does not mean that every time the function is called, it would be given the same address.*

---

> I expected the following code to fail to compile

You violate neither constness as described above, so there is no reason to expect this.

> because the str() returns string by value that will keep on changing on every call

See specifically explanation above <sup>1</sup>.

---

> (1) Why does the pointer is not constant in the method argument after compilation.
>
> ```
> query_nonblocking(char const*, unsigned long):
> ```

Because const and non-const arguments are treated the same by the language for overload resolution purposes. The constness of the argument is indistinguishable to the outside of the function definition, so as long as the compiler has checked that the function definition does not violate the constness, it no longer needs to care about the constness.

Comment: Perhaps the example I have posted is too simple to make any sense in practice. But I get the gist.  Thanks.